# Use Fortran module in C++ with std::thread

Tags: c++, module, fortran, openmp, stdthread

I would like to run a Fortran90 function with different settings in different `std::threads`, that uses many modules to store the settings and some general data. The problem I see is, that Fortran modules are like singleton objects. When I call the function with two threads they do work on the same module. Is there a way to make modules threadprivate like with openmp?

For example with openmp a module with threadprivate data looks like this:

```
MODULE EXAMPLE
  USE OMP_LIB
  ! some threadprivate data:
  INTEGER                                          :: VALUE = 0
    ! make value threadprivate.
    !$OMP THREADPRIVATE(VALUE)
  CONTAINS
END MODULE EXAMPLE
```

Can I do something similar for the `std::thread`?

Comment: There is no standard that covers this, but at least on some ELF systems (most notably Linux) the GNU OpenMP runtime and `std::thread` both use the ELF TLS to store thread-local variables. Thus, OpenMP thread-private variables are also thread-local in C++ threads. Again, this is neither standard nor portable.

Comment: Note that even on Linux there are more runtimes than just GOMP. They may be compatible in this feature but they are not compatible in general. But C++ threads are very likely to be implemented on top of the same low-level layer (e.g. POSIX threads) as OpenMP threads, that is quite natural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ standard threads are completely alien to Fortran. 
there is nothing you can do in Fortran,

You have to implement everything yourself in a way that stores the data in some other way and not in global (module) variables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I was hoping to avoid the reimplemetation of the library. I guess there might not be an other way.